# How to use FormData while testing API post request in opentest

Tags: opentest

Hi I am getting below error while using FormData in Post Method for opentest

my code:

`var data = new FormData(); data.append("name", "test")`

and I am getting below error:

```
at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.evalScript(TestActor.java:1441)
at org.getopentest.base.ScriptAction.run(ScriptAction.java:32)
at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.executeAction(TestActor.java:1527)
at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.executeActionByDef(TestActor.java:1695)
... 4 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "FormData" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
    at
```

jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
at org.getopentest.base.TestActor.evalScript(TestActor.java:1427)

Answer (score 0):

The `FormData` object is only available in web browsers and is not part of the OpenTest API. If you are trying to send a request using the HttpRequest keyword, you should be able to build this simply by concatenating the key/value pairs for the form fields and their values this way:

```
field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
```

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).